# RSS Feed from Google

Tags: rss

I am using a Telerik control and it requires my to enter a XmlDataSource.

What I like to do is to get a Google RSS Feed for news related to "Lung Disease"

How do I go about doing this? How do I get the xml url for this?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

This can be done simply by going to Google News and typing what the search is. At the bottom, there is a `Create Alert` button. Click on it to get the RSS link.